# Changing button classes dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<button class="changeMe"> Click Me </button>
```

```
$(".changeMe").on("click", function(){
    console.log("I should only work the first time!")
    $("changeMe").addClass("secondClass").removeClass("changeMe");
});

$(".secondClass").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Now I should Work!")
});
```

This is basically what my code looks like.

I click the button. 
Chrome developer tools show that the class was removed.
I click the button again, and the same bit of jquery code runs even thou the class its pointing too dosnt exist.

How do I stop that from happening.

EDIT:: Ooopss forgot the dot. I have the dot in my solution. This is just for demonstration purposes. Added dot.

Comment: You need to use event delegation because you are changing classes manually. Also `.` is needed for selecting class names.

Comment: You forgot the _dot_ to denote the class :)

Comment: You need to learn about how selectors work before in Jquery, use dot to select a a class or # to select by id, or even another kind of selectors, please read following link for basic CSS selector: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add `.` before class name, so it will be `$(".changeMe")` and `$(".secondClass")`

2) Use `$(document).on("click")` event

Try:

```js
$(document).on("click",".changeMe", function(){
    console.log("I should only work the first time!")
    $(".changeMe").addClass("secondClass")
    $(".changeMe").removeClass("changeMe");
});

$(document).on("click",".secondClass", function(){
    console.log("Now I should Work!")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="changeMe"> Click Me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
$("body").on("click", '.changeMe', function(){
    console.log("I should only work the first time!")
    $(".changeMe").addClass("secondClass").removeClass("changeMe");
});

$("body").on("click", '.secondClass', function(){
    console.log("Now I should Work!")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on clicking `.secondClass`. You have to bind the events dynamically.

```
$(document).on("click",".secondClass", function(){
    console.log("Now I should Work!")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation because you are changing classes manually. Also `.` is needed for selecting class names.

**Edit :** Instead of **event delegation**, you can use the following, bind the event to the second class, after the class is added.

Use **[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** for binding to work only once.

```js
$(".changeMe").one("click", function(e){
    console.log("I should only work the first time!")
    $(".changeMe").addClass("secondClass").removeClass("changeMe");
    $(".secondClass").on("click", function(){
        console.log("Now I should Work!")
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="changeMe"> Click Me </button>
```

Comment: Thanks this fits the app perfectly. Will make sure to remember the .one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 $(".changeMe").on("click", function(e){

    if($(e.target).is('.changeMe')) {
    console.log("I should only work the first time!")
    $(".changeMe").removeClass("changeMe").addClass("secondClass");
    } else {
    console.log("Now I should Work!");
    }
});
```